# Can we customize TextEditBox node in roku?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am working on a roku app using scene graph component. I am using **TextEditBox** node to take input.
My issue is when I type new character after specific length, newly character becomes hidden with "..."
but I want to show last entered character.

Simply I want behaviour like **input box** in HTML or **roSearchScreen** in brightScript.

Can anyone suggest any ideas on how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a  bug in said component. Bring the question to Roku dev.forum and hope they'll fix it
https://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=96422

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the length of the text, so it won't get collapsed.